# Declaring a Handle for a specific window

Tags: spy++

I have just used spy++ to find the handle of a window that I need, but spy++ is giving me a number:

```
Window Handle: 00010080
```

And I mean... usually when you declare a handle its done like:

```
HWND windowHandle;
```

Question::  So I am guessing that `00010080` is some sort of `ID` or something, but how do I use it to declare the right handle that I want in my code?

I mean I cant do 
`HWND windowHandle = 00010080;` (haha if you know what I mean, so how do I use this number to get the window handle?)

Comment: Did you forgot to tag java, python, VB etc?

Comment: The HWND is created by the OS at runtime!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value given to you by Spy++ is the same one returned by calls like `CreateWindow`. Using Spy++ to acquire this value and then using it in your program is not the most optimal solution as the value will change each time the target application starts.

Instead I suggest you use [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`FindWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or even [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). These are the same calls used by Spy++ to get a list of windows. For example the following will search for the first top level window created using a class name of *SomeWindowClass*.

```
HWND hwnd = ::FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, "SomeWindowClass", NULL);
```

Comment: awesome comment, was a real help! I am trying to use the SendMessage(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam) function to a window saying that a button was clicked, but I am having problems because there are 3 buttons in that window... so doing what you said previously would give me the hWnd to the window... BN_CLICK would be my msg... but how would the function know which of the 3 buttons is being clicked?

Comment: You can use [`GetDlgItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481(v=vs.85).aspx) on the parent window to get the handle of the button by id.

Answer (score 2):

HWND is as HANDLE

HANDLE is PVOID

So, just assign your number to variable:

```
HWND hwnd = (HWND) 0x00010080;
```

don't forget that hwnd is different for each application run.

reference [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this is really useful advice!!

Comment: the problem i've noticed is that the handle I got is only temporary. If I close the program and reopen it, the value I got from spy++ won't stay the same.... For that reason your method wouldn't work for my case